# Go through MSMQ one message at a time in powershell

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am currently trying to write a script that will go through a message queue and delete/send to another subqueue each message if a certain string is in the body.

In Pseudo code I am currently trying to implement

```
$queue = 'My Queue'
foreach($message in $queue)
    {
    if ($message.body.Contains("matchstring")
        {
         $message.delete OR $message.movequeue
         }
    }
```

I am currently using [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") in powershell but I am not sure if it contains all the functionality I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in PowerShell.  Here's some simple code to get you started and connected to a queue:

```
$queuePath = ("Direct=OS:SERVER\private$\PRIVATEQUEUE")
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
$queue.GetAllMessages()
```

Use $queue | gm and the MSDN to get you where you need to be.